# Javascript Node API pass res value to all my other function without calling the function

Tags: javascript

**Need Help** 
Can anyone please suggest me How can i pass token_value to my all other function. token_value is the sucs response value. If i call the login() function
it requires me to pass username and password. so I cant call the function. But I need to pass the token_value that generated once i login.

$("#submit_login").click(login);

```
   var token_value = "";
 function login(){
        var login = {  
               username: $("#username > input").val(),
               password: $("#password > input").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:9000/login",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(login)
        })
        .done(function(res){
          token_value = res.token;
              $("#test2").append(token_value);
          alert("You are logged in successfully");      
        })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log(error);
                    alert ("could not sign in");
        });

      return  token_value;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried storing token value in cookie and getting it from there whenever the token value is required.

Comment: Thank for the suggest, Can you show me please how ?